# How to reset CardView background?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview, android-background, android-color

I have a CardView which is getting colored after a button click ("reveal right answer" functionality). The card needs to get back to it's original color for the next question. I am using the default Android color, but I couldn't find the value I need to reset to (`R.attr.cardBackgroundColor` turns my card blue...), so I used tint like so:

```
@BindingAdapter("isRight", "showResult")
fun CardView.setCardTint(
    isRight: Boolean,
    showResult: Boolean,
) {
    background.setTintList(null)
    if (showResult) {
        val colorRes = if (isRight) R.color.result_right
        else R.color.result_wrong

        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes))
    }
}
```

This works great, but now I need to change the colors to gradients. For that I need to go back to the original solution and change the background itself (to the gradient drawables) - and to my original problem: How to reset the CardView background to it's Android default value?

Comment: tried to save a reference of the background before you change it ? so you can reset it again ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that. Plus, I just realized that I need a border color too, so I have to use drawables, and I need to create one for the default case - I need the resource/attribute used by default...

Comment: You can check background color of Cardview, and according current color you can set any other background color to cardview.

Comment: I know, but that means keeping a constant of my own for the color, which I would like to avoid in order to keep with the android dark theme if it changes. I am now exploring a solution of changing the `LinearLayout` that I have inside the CardView. Setting it's bg to transparent will show the default CardView color as I wanted.